# How to get and save checkboxes names into a list with tkinter, python 3.6.5

Tags: python, python-3.x, checkbox, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I would like to to use tkinter and checkboxes to make a selection of files in a directory and save those files names in a list when I press a button:

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import playsound
import os
import glob
import unidecode
import pickle
import random
import tkinter
from tkinter.constants import *

ldv = os.listdir("D:/FFOutput/")
i = 0
ldv1 = []
while i < len(ldv):
    ldv1.append(unidecode.unidecode(ldv[i]))
    i += 1
print(ldv1)

root = tkinter.Tk()
frame = tkinter.Frame(root, relief=RIDGE, borderwidth=10)
frame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
label = tkinter.Label(frame, text="choose file(s)")
label.pack(fill=X, expand=1)


a = 0
while a < len(ldv1):
    bouton = tkinter.Checkbutton(root, text=ldv1[a], command=print(ldv1[a]))
    a += 1
    bouton.pack()

button = tkinter.Button(frame, text="Exit", command=root.destroy)
button.pack(side=BOTTOM)

lr = []

buttonregister = tkinter.Button(root, text="Register checked files names in list lr and close tk")
buttonregister.pack(side=BOTTOM)

print(lr)

root.mainloop()
```

When I click on buttonregister, I would like to append the files names into the list lr and close the frame. [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTpaH.png)

In that example, I wish to print(lr) `"['alors soyez pret.mp3','c'est bien.mp3']"` in the shell when I click the button.

Answer (score 1):

For a Checkbutton to hold a value, a BoolVar (or any other var) from tkinter must be used. This is usually quite tedious as you would have to make a variable for every Checkbutton. This can be avoided by sub-classing the Checkbutton and adding storage for a variable. Since you require the text as well, we can also use the class to store the text value.

Replacing the Checkbuttons with the class below will do this.

```
class CheckBox(tkinter.Checkbutton):
    boxes = []  # Storage for all buttons

    def __init__(self, master=None, **options):
        tkinter.Checkbutton.__init__(self, master, options)  # Subclass checkbutton to keep other methods
        self.boxes.append(self)
        self.var = tkinter.BooleanVar()  # var used to store checkbox state (on/off)
        self.text = self.cget('text')  # store the text for later
        self.configure(variable=self.var)  # set the checkbox to use our var
```

We would then use the class to make the buttons as follows:

```
a=0
while a<len(ldv1):
   bouton=CheckBox(tk, text=ldv1[a], command=print(ldv1[a]))  # Replace Checkbutton
   a=a+1
   bouton.pack()
```

And finally, to get the values when the window is closed, you can loop through CheckBox.buttons for each button's value. You would need to add this after the mainloop or add it to a function.

```
for box in CheckBox.boxes:
    if box.var.get():  # Checks if the button is ticked
        lr.append(box.text)

print(lr)
```

Comment: It works perfectly, thank you Zekii. Chekbutton should be by default like your CheckBox.